# How do I find users created exactly multiple whole months/quarters ago in Postgres SQL?

Tags: postgresql, date

How do I find all the user records created exactly multiple whole months/quarters ago in Postgres SQL?  Is it possible?

In Postgres, you can find a date which is exactly 1 month away from a datetime field, like:

```
select created_at + interval '1 month' from users limit 1;
?column?          
----------------------------
2016-10-05 17:05:14.811537
(1 row)
```

If today is 9/27/2016, I want to find **all** the user records created on 8/27/2016, 7/27/2016, 6/27/2016, ... 1/27/2015, etc, etc.  How do I do this in SQL?

Note this isn't simply a comparison of date due to the fact that some months have 31 days while others have 28, 29, 30 days.

If today is 2/28/2015 (non-leap year), I want all the users created on the following dates:  1/28/2015, 1/29/2015, 1/30/2015, 1/31/2015, 12/28/2014, 12/29/2014, 12/30/2014, 12/31/2014, etc etc.

If today is 2/28/2016 (leap year), I want all the users created on the following dates:  1/28/2015, 12/28/2014, 11/28/2014, etc etc. (But not on 1/29/2015, 1/30/2015, 1/31/2015, as those users will be picked up the next day, see below).

If today is 2/29/2016 (leap year), I want all the users created on the following dates:  1/29/2015, 1/30/2015, 1/31/2015, 12/29/2014, 12/30/2014, 12/31/2014, etc etc.

If today is 3/31/2016, I want all the users created on 12/31/2015, 1/31/2016, but not anyone created in February 2016 because they would have been picked on previous days of March 2016.

How do I do the above with quarters instead of months?

Another question related to this is performance.  If I create an index on `created_at`, would a whole table scan be avoided if I do this type of queries?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... If You think of it, You want to compare day number in reality, right? So You should do just that:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    users 
where 
    date_part('day', created_at) = date_part('day', current_timestamp) 
    OR
    (
    -- Check if this is the last day of month
        extract(month from current_timestamp + '1day'::interval) <> extract(month from current_timestamp)
        AND 
        date_part('day', created_at) > date_part('day', current_timestamp) 
    )
limit 
    1
;
```

And regarding Your index question - yes.

Inspiration for checking last day of a month taken from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20100225172043.GA1354%40a-kretschmer.de).

Basically, if I still do not get Your requirement, You should be able to easily modify my code to meet it, if You understand it. :)

Comment: It's not that simple.  If today is 2/28/2015, I want the users created on 1/28/2015, 1/29/2015, 1/30/2015, 1/31/2015 etc.  But if today is 2/28/2016, I want the users created on 1/28/2016 etc, but not on 1/29/2016.  If today is 2/29/2016, I want the users created on 1/29/2016, 1/30/2016, 1/31/2016, etc.  Because months have different number of days, we have to round it so to speak.

Comment: If today is 2/28/2015, I'm not sure if your code works.  In addition, if today is 4/30/2016, it needs the users created on 1/30/2016, 1/31/2016.  Where is this logic?

Comment: I think I dont understand what do You want. Can You please state in words, in Your question exact and full descripion of requirement?

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: Yes, I think I get Your logic now - You want to compare exact days, but if it is the last day of month, all days in other months that are greater than todays day should also be matched.... I updated the query accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124312/discussion-between-t-z-and-zack-xu).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When I first asked the question, I assumed PostgresSQL might have some built-in function that does this.  But calculating this way works.  Regarding index, as we discussed, index would not be used if the query is as above, because the index is on created_at (a datetime stamp), and we are querying on date (a single integer between 1 and 31).  So to make this performant, we need to create a separate column to store the date and create an index on this.